# Data restoration of a RAID1 drive from a QNAP NAS

Tags: hard-drive, network-attached-storage, data-recovery, disaster-recovery, qnap

I have a dead QNAP HS-251 NAS enclosure, using two disks in RAID1. The enclosure is dead, but the drives seem fine. I would like to recover the data on it. .

Of course, I have no backup... Stupidly,I thought that RAID was sufficient and that in case of a crash, I would always have either of my drive usable...

I tried to mount one of them on a single USB enclosure, but I cannot find standard partitions on it (even Linux'). I tried some "recovery software" but it seems to only try to find files in a "raw way" without caring of any structure.

Is there a way of recovering data (and if possible the directory structure) without buying another NAS enclosure ?

Comment: Connect *both* drives to Linux machine (I don't want to go into deep details why this matters in the comment; I had already explained this several times here), Then boot, run `lsblk` and `blkid` and [update your question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1147252/edit) with the output.